# iOS startup screen image zooming in?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm getting my app ready to submit to the app store and have been reading the guidelines on the startup screen. It seems apple prefer it to be something that makes it look like your app is already loaded even when it isn't.

I decided to use the background image of my app as the startup screen. That way the skeleton of the app will be there and the buttons and text will load in.

I used a copy of the image but renamed it to Default-568h@2x.png.

It works but when it launches, it has that default zoom affect but it seems to zoom in bigger than the actual image size and so doesn't transition nicely into the app.

Any ideas why this happens and what I can do?

Thanks

Comment: OK thinking about it, it seems that my background for the app is 640 x 1136 but when running an app, some of the pixels are taken up by the bar at the top with the time etc.

I'm guessing using the startup image with the resolution of 640x1136 doesn't have to worry about the bar with the time and so looks zoomed in when loading?

Comment: If you are hiding status bar while launching then you shoud take image of size 640x1136 and if you are showing status bar get image of size 640x1096. You can chose to show/hide status bar while launching in Info.plist(or Target->Summary tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way around this.

I found out that the status bar at the top is 40 pixels for retina and 20 for non retina.

I then created a black background in the size of the full iphone 5 resolution. I then got my startup image (actually the background for my app) but resized it down 40 pixels vertically.

I then put this on top of the black background I created and lined up the bottom.

I then merged the layers and used this as the startup image. It worked perfectly, the startup image loads up and then my app opens up right on top of it perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone, the default.png image should contain the status bar (if it is visible in your app).

On the iPad, the status bar shall be left out.

Thus, the default image size should be ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the status bar being included or excluded in the Default images. According to apple all the iPhone Default.pngs should have the status bars included while iPad should have the status bar left out. (Unless of course your application hides the status bar)